# Service Fabric: There was an error during image download

Tags: azure, docker, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to deploy a Docker Compose to Service Fabric. The cluster created from Azure Marketplace consists of five UbuntuServer 16.04-LTS.

I'm using the 'Deploy docker-compose application to a Service Fabric cluster' task to deploy the docker compose file. But when Service Fabric deploys the container, I receive the following error (In Service Fabric Explorer): `There was an error during download. Container image download failed for ImageName=xxxx. 
DockerRequest returned StatusCode=InternalServerError with ResponseBody=`. The image has been pushed to Azure Container Registry. I can docker pull and run the image locally. Does anyone have a clue on what could be going on?

Comment: Did you provide correct credentials to your registry? `-RegistryUserName` `-RegistryPassword` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose

Comment: I'm using VSTS release definition for deployment. I select username and password under Registry Credentials Source and fill in the right value.

Comment: sfctl is also tried but it turns out the same issue. @LoekD

Comment: What happens if you use PowerShell to deploy to the cluster, from localhost? Does that work?

Comment: From localhost, i used Connect-ServiceFabricCluster to connect, which does not work. The result is `WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM... `

Comment: For a secured cluster, make sure to pass the client certificate like this: `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -X509Credential -ConnectionEndpoint cluster.westeurope.clou
dapp.azure.com:19000 -ServerCertThumbprint 12345678903D601E16FC3D -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValu
e 12345678903D601E16FC3D -StoreName My -StoreLocation CurrentUser` when connecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172490/discussion-between-matthewxie-and-loekd).

Comment: Since the chat is not available anymore, how did you solve this issue? @Matthewxie

Answer (score 0):

The container registry it seems has to be configured with credentials.
Once configured in Settings->Access Keys, take the admin user and password.

Run below:

```
sfctl compose create --deployment-name NAME --file-path docker-compose.yml  --user ADMIN_USER --has-pass
```

This would prompt for the password, the pull would go on fine now.

or try the encyption ( I did not explore it)

Please explore this link for other options:
[Configure container repository credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/configure-container-repository-credentials)

You can also try making the registry public for specific IP range ( machine from where you are deploying )

[Configure public registry access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-access-selected-networks)